# Is there a way to run an IDE like VSCode from a cloud instance?

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, ipython

I know that with R you can run RStudio as a browser instance directly from a server/cloud instance, so you access the IDE via browser, and that IDE has access to files/data available on that instance (similar to what Jupyterlab does).

Similarly i wonder if there is a way to run VSCode (or some other full feature IDE) as a browser instance on something like a google dataproc, so instead of using Jupyter to run code and access data, you would use the IDE.

I realize there are ways to run a local instance of an IDE and connect to a server/cloud instance, but in some cases these connections are blocked by firewalls and you have no way of running code on the instance other than via browser/jupyter, so i was wondering if there was some other way to do this.

Comment: There is https://vscode.dev/, or solutions like RDP/TeamViewer on the web

Comment: Have you had a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server ?

Comment: This brand new feature is designed for that: https://cloud.google.com/workstations

Answer (score 0):

As @guillaume blaquiere suggested :

[Cloud Workstation](https://cloud.google.com/workstations) is the brand new feature is designed for that

Fully managed development environments built to meet the needs of security-sensitive enterprises. It enhances the security of development environments while accelerating developer onboarding and productivity.

1. Access secure and fast development environments anytime via browser or local IDE
2. Enable administrators to easily provision, scale, manage, and secure development environments
3. Customize development environments with your preferred IDE and through custom container images